# Can you see why @Output will not emit to it's parent component?

Tags: angular

I can not figure out why the child component will not emit to my parent component. Here are my components.

Parent Component:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flights',
  template: `<app-date-picker (dateRange)="onRangeSelect($event)"></app-date-picker>`,
  styleUrls: ['./flights.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class FlightsComponent {
  onRangeSelect(range: string){
    console.log("From Parent =>", range);
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-date-picker',
    template: `<button (click)="go('From Child')">Emit</button>`,
    styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
  })

export class DatePickerComponent {

  @Output() dateRange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  go(message: string) {
    console.log('Button Clicked ', message);
    this.dateRange.emit(message);
  }
}
```

When I hit the 'Emit' button, the console logs the message, 'Button Clicked  From Child' but as far as I can tell dateRange is not emitting because the console logs in the parent component do not happen. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: It may spell mistake in your ```ParentComponent.html``` or you may try without ChangeDetector.

Comment: I removed all changeDetection from everywhere in my app and things still aren't working as expected. I'm pretty sure I have things spelled correctly because the template for the mark up is there in the ts file for the parent. Thank you for the ideas and input.

Comment: Can you prodcue a stack blitz?

Comment: Well, it works fine on stack blitz so it must have something to do with one of the other packages i have installed. I'm going to keep working on it and update this question after i get things straightened out. Thanks for pointing me to stack blitz, I've only used it passively in the past.

Comment: In my app.module, I had my child component in the bootstrap array of ngModule. Once I removed it from there, everything works as expected. Thanks again everyone for taking a look.